# Pandas merging data from specific column

Tags: python, csv, pandas

I am trying to merge data to create a new dataframe.  I have two dataframes and  am trying to print KEYS Value to the third dataframe if it equals any of the numbers in the following columns

```
df2          
                 0           1           2           3           4   \
KEYS                                                                  
FIT-3982  2024.0016   0101.0007        None        None        None   
FIT-3980  1140.0107        None        None        None        None   
FIT-3979  1907.0007   1907.0012   1907.0019   1907.0020   1907.0021   
FIT-3975  0117.0002   0117.0008        None        None        None   
FIT-3974  3004.0130        None        None        None        None   
FIT-3970  0114.0001   0114.0002   0101.0010   0114.0004   0114.0005   
FIT-3967  0113.0001    0113.009        None        None        None   
FIT-3964  1901.0017   1901.0019   0101.0005   1906.0015   1906.0028   
FIT-3963  1801.0038   0101.0002   1803.0020   1803.0021   1805.0020   
FIT-3960  0104.0001   0104.0009   0104.0014   0104.0015   0104.0016
```

This is the df1

```
                                       ID     TC_NUM
0  dialog_testcase_0101.0001_greeting.xml  0101.0001
1  dialog_testcase_0101.0002_greeting.xml  0101.0002
2  dialog_testcase_0101.0003_greeting.xml  0101.0003
3  dialog_testcase_0101.0004_greeting.xml  0101.0004
4  dialog_testcase_0101.0005_greeting.xml  0101.0005
5  dialog_testcase_0101.0006_greeting.xml  0101.0006
6  dialog_testcase_0101.0007_greeting.xml  0101.0007
7  dialog_testcase_0101.0008_greeting.xml  0101.0008
8  dialog_testcase_0101.0009_greeting.xml  0101.0009
9  dialog_testcase_0101.0010_greeting.xml  0101.0010

WHAT I WANT

df3-final          
                                       ID     TC_NUM   KEYS
0  dialog_testcase_0101.0001_greeting.xml  0101.0002  FIT-3963
1  dialog_testcase_0101.0002_greeting.xml  0101.0003
2  dialog_testcase_0101.0003_greeting.xml  0101.0004
3  dialog_testcase_0101.0004_greeting.xml  0101.0005  FIT-3964
4  dialog_testcase_0101.0005_greeting.xml  0101.0006
5  dialog_testcase_0101.0006_greeting.xml  0101.0007  FIT-3982
6  dialog_testcase_0101.0007_greeting.xml  0101.0008
7  dialog_testcase_0101.0008_greeting.xml  0101.0009
8  dialog_testcase_0101.0009_greeting.xml  0101.0010
9  dialog_testcase_0101.0010_greeting.xml  0101.0011
```

code so far..

```
df1 = pd.read_csv('csv1.csv')


df2 = pd.read_csv('InitialQuerydataOpen.csv')

print df2.head(10)

df2.set_index('KEYS',inplace=True)

#change separator from `, ` to `,` (removed space)
#df2 = df2.TC_NUM.str[3:].str.split(',', expand=True).unstack().reset_index(drop=True, level=0).reset_index(name='TC_NUM')
df2 = df2.TC_NUM.str[3:].str.split(',', expand=True)



mergedOpen = pd.merge(df1, df2, on='df1[TC_NUM]', how='left')
print mergedOpen
```

Comment: What columns in df1 and df2 are you trying to use in your merge?

Comment: I want to merge *I think* or concat? ..KEYS onto the end of df3 if TCNUM = number from df2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Setup

```
import pandas as pd
from StringIO import StringIO

text2 = """KEYS                 0           1           2           3           4 
FIT-3982  2024.0016   0101.0007        None        None        None   
FIT-3980  1140.0107        None        None        None        None   
FIT-3979  1907.0007   1907.0012   1907.0019   1907.0020   1907.0021   
FIT-3975  0117.0002   0117.0008        None        None        None   
FIT-3974  3004.0130        None        None        None        None   
FIT-3970  0114.0001   0114.0002   0101.0010   0114.0004   0114.0005   
FIT-3967  0113.0001    0113.009        None        None        None   
FIT-3964  1901.0017   1901.0019   0101.0005   1906.0015   1906.0028   
FIT-3963  1801.0038   0101.0002   1803.0020   1803.0021   1805.0020   
FIT-3960  0104.0001   0104.0009   0104.0014   0104.0015   0104.0016   """

df2 = pd.read_csv(StringIO(text2), delim_whitespace=True, index_col=0, dtype=str)

df2[df2 == 'None'] = None

text1 = """                                       ID     TC_NUM
0  dialog_testcase_0101.0001_greeting.xml  0101.0001
1  dialog_testcase_0101.0002_greeting.xml  0101.0002
2  dialog_testcase_0101.0003_greeting.xml  0101.0003
3  dialog_testcase_0101.0004_greeting.xml  0101.0004
4  dialog_testcase_0101.0005_greeting.xml  0101.0005
5  dialog_testcase_0101.0006_greeting.xml  0101.0006
6  dialog_testcase_0101.0007_greeting.xml  0101.0007
7  dialog_testcase_0101.0008_greeting.xml  0101.0008
8  dialog_testcase_0101.0009_greeting.xml  0101.0009
9  dialog_testcase_0101.0010_greeting.xml  0101.0010"""

df1 = pd.read_csv(StringIO(text1), delim_whitespace=True, dtype=str)
```

#### Solution

```
def get_key(df2, tc_num):
    df2test = (df2 == tc_num).any(axis=1)
    df2test = df2test[df2test]
    if not df2test.empty:
        return df2test.index[0]

df1['keys'] = df1.apply(lambda x: get_key(df2, x.TC_NUM), axis=1)

print df1

                                       ID     TC_NUM      keys
0  dialog_testcase_0101.0001_greeting.xml  0101.0001      None
1  dialog_testcase_0101.0002_greeting.xml  0101.0002  FIT-3963
2  dialog_testcase_0101.0003_greeting.xml  0101.0003      None
3  dialog_testcase_0101.0004_greeting.xml  0101.0004      None
4  dialog_testcase_0101.0005_greeting.xml  0101.0005  FIT-3964
5  dialog_testcase_0101.0006_greeting.xml  0101.0006      None
6  dialog_testcase_0101.0007_greeting.xml  0101.0007  FIT-3982
7  dialog_testcase_0101.0008_greeting.xml  0101.0008      None
8  dialog_testcase_0101.0009_greeting.xml  0101.0009      None
9  dialog_testcase_0101.0010_greeting.xml  0101.0010  FIT-3970
```

#### Explanation

- Make sure dtypes are string or object.  `dtype=str`.  Could have done `df1.astype(str)`.
- use `any(axis=1)` to check if string is in any of the columns.

Answer (score 3):

You can `stack` `df2`, do some quick formatting, and then use `merge`:

```
df2 = df2.stack().reset_index(level=0).rename(columns={0: 'TC_NUM'})
result = df1.merge(df2, how='left', on=['TC_NUM'])'
```

The resulting output:

```
                                       ID     TC_NUM      KEYS
0  dialog_testcase_0101.0001_greeting.xml  0101.0001       NaN
1  dialog_testcase_0101.0002_greeting.xml  0101.0002  FIT-3963
2  dialog_testcase_0101.0003_greeting.xml  0101.0003       NaN
3  dialog_testcase_0101.0004_greeting.xml  0101.0004       NaN
4  dialog_testcase_0101.0005_greeting.xml  0101.0005  FIT-3964
5  dialog_testcase_0101.0006_greeting.xml  0101.0006       NaN
6  dialog_testcase_0101.0007_greeting.xml  0101.0007  FIT-3982
7  dialog_testcase_0101.0008_greeting.xml  0101.0008       NaN
8  dialog_testcase_0101.0009_greeting.xml  0101.0009       NaN
9  dialog_testcase_0101.0010_greeting.xml  0101.0010  FIT-3970
```

Using `merge` appears to be more efficient:

```
%timeit df1.merge(df2.stack().reset_index(level=0).rename(columns={0:'TC_NUM'}), how='left', on=['TC_NUM'])
100 loops, best of 3: 3.84 ms per loop

%timeit df1.apply(lambda x: get_key(df2, x.TC_NUM), axis=1)
100 loops, best of 3: 10.4 ms per loop
```